# Convert JSON to YAML. Parsing JSON to YAML

Tags: java, json, parsing, yaml

I'm working with configuration files so I need to convert JSON to YAML.
For example I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [ "qux","quxx"],
  "corge": null,
  "grault": 1,
  "garply": true,
  "waldo": "false",
  "fred": "undefined",
  "emptyArray": [],
  "emptyObject": {},
  "emptyString": ""
}
```

The result should be YAML:

```
foo: "bar"
baz: 
  - "qux"
  - "quxx"
corge: null
grault: 1
garply: true
waldo: "false"
fred: "undefined"
emptyArray: []
emptyObject: {}
emptyString: ""
```

Could you help me?

Comment: According to the [YAML spec (section 1.3)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), "YAML can therefore be viewed as a natural superset of JSON ...", and "... every JSON file is also a valid YAML file."

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you need convert JSONobject to yaml (string). you need. Firstly get json string, then map, after that you can convert to yaml.
Here the code:

```
  // this is your json object
  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(map);
  // get json string
  String prettyJSONString = jsonobject.toString(4);
  // mapping
  Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(prettyJSONString);
  // convert to yaml string (yaml formatted string)
  String output = yaml.dump(map2);
```

Comment: could you explain your answer briefly? Where you declare "jsonPrettyPrintString"

Comment: I'm really sorry for late response, I edited answer. @MurugesanEra

Comment: Please explain the yaml variable.

Comment: Which map should I pass here ? How to convert the json string to map .

Answer (score 55):

You can convert JSON to YAML with two lines of code in [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLMapper;

public class Library {

    public String asYaml(String jsonString) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        // parse JSON
        JsonNode jsonNodeTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonString);
        // save it as YAML
        String jsonAsYaml = new YAMLMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonNodeTree);
        return jsonAsYaml;
    }

}
```

You will need to add dependencies to Jackson Core, DataBind and DataFormat YAML. Below is a snippet for Gradle:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.8.6'
```

Comment: Saved me a ton of trouble. Great answer.

Comment: to get rid of | --- in first lines of output yaml, you can convert JSON to HashMap and write this HashMap as yaml file

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one liner for a file, suitable for sticking in a bash script.  This should work on most default pythons on most systems:

```
python -c 'import json; import yaml; print(yaml.dump(json.load(open("inputfile"))))'
```

Comment: This recipe works, but writing it to a file would be better.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsontoyaml.com/

this website may can help you. It can be used in
Bash,
JavaScript,
JavaScript (browser only),
Ruby,
Python,
Perl,
Java..

Comment: I'm against down-voting this. No where in the question it is mentioned as to provide "programmatical way" So this answer also valid.

Comment: @PasinduJay The tags provide the necessary context - question is tagged Java.

Comment: After almost 10 years, the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you consider [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It converts between JSON, YML, and other formats.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).

Answer (score 1):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used to convert between JSON and YAML

```bash
yq -o yaml --indent 2 --prettyPrint --colors
```

```yaml
foo: bar
baz:
  - qux
  - quxx
corge: null
grault: 1
garply: true
waldo: "false"
fred: undefined
emptyArray: []
emptyObject: {}
emptyString: ""
```

(XML and property files can also be transformed using `yq`)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
function yaml_validate {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read())'
}

function yaml2json {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read())))'
}

function yaml2json_pretty {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read()), indent=2, sort_keys=False))'
}

function json_validate {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; json.loads(sys.stdin.read())'
}

function json2yaml {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(yaml.dump(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())))'
}
```

More Bash tricks at http://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts