# SpringBoot config json format property files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'd like to know if it's possible that Spring is able to get config properties from json format files.

I've tried to find something but up to now, I've only been able to get that the only formats are yml and properties files.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can just use jackson to read the json file

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564475/3465242 Hope this help.

Comment: check this page [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-json-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `.yml` and `.properies` format for application properties.
More information in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: What about that [code](https://github.com/raffaelespazzoli/credscontroller/blob/master/examples/spring-legacy-example/src/main/java/com/raffa/InitConfiguration.java#L27)